# How to fix import ssl error in Apache server(Windows)

Tags: windows, apache, ssl, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to design a RESTful API with a Flask app using **mod_wsgi** on an **Apache** server, and I'm getting an error with importing the **ssl** module in the **Apache** server.
I have installed Apache 2.4 from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/, and mod_wsgi using pip, configured it in the Apache server.

I created a simple Flask app:

```
    from flask import Flask   '
app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "Hello World"
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

I created a web.wsgi file:

```
    import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/chant/myapp')
from final_app import app as application
```

and used it to configure a virtual host for the Flask App, by pasting the following code in http-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
    ServerName  localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/chant/myapp/web.wsgi"
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/chant/myapp"
ErrorLog "C:/Users/chant/myapp/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Users/chant/myapp/logs/access.log" common
```

My error log shows:

```
    File "c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\Lib\\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>\r
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate\r
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.\r
```

Though I tried testing the import module and it ran in python, though it is not importing in the Apache server.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed later that an important part of the deployment of the Flask app is that Python should be installed for all users, else Apache server is not able to import the ssl module.

Hope this helps!